# Why give me this error "can't convert String into Hash" with RoR ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper and ActionController::UrlWriter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink, helper

I have this in my controller

```
     include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
     include ActionController::UrlWriter
     include ApplicationHelper::TextHelper
```

TextHelper has something like this

```
var = {
    "name1"=>link_to('string1', home_page_path),
    "name2"=>link_to('string2', :controller=>'xxxxx/xxxx', :action=>'info_xxx', :return_to=>'/xxxxxxxx'),
    "name3"=>link_to('string3', 'http://www.url.com', :target=>'_blank'),
    "name4"=>link_to('string4', :controller => 'xxxxxx/xxxxx')
  }
```

`name2` and `name4` give me the error "can't convert String into Hash", this is because `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper` and `ActionController::UrlWriter` has a different implementation for `url_for` and one of them does not manage `Hash`.

If I remove  `ActionController::UrlWriter` I get the error

```
undefined method `url_for' for nil:NilClass
```

and if I remove `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper` give me

```
undefined method `link_to' for #<xxxxxx::xxxxx::xxxxxxController:0xc3d276c>
```

I am using ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 2.3.8 and I can not change anything in var in `TextHelper` and I can not change any implementation in `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper` and `ActionController::UrlWriter`.

Any solution, please